# Projection of a function on another

Tags: vector-spaces, inner-products

I was going through a question paper of an exam and this particular problem caught my eyes. The inner product formula given there is confusing me. I am not getting why there is a additional function multiplied there and what will be a projection of a function on another. I tried to integrate putting $f(x)$ as $1$ and $g(x)$ as $x^2$ and got the inner product but don't know how to proceed from here to get the projection.
[Click here to see the problem.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t9Hck.jpg)

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Can you please tell me if it is more appropriate now?

Comment: It's better now, but you should avoid using pictures.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Thanks! Will do next time.